# Unity Ads Vs Unity Ads 2.0

Tags: unity-game-engine, beta, unityads

I want to ask is there any difference in revenue by using new unity ads 2.0 as compare to unity ads

[Unity Ads](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21027)

[Unity Ads 2.0](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/66123)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Unity Ads** support **Unity 4.2.2** or higher. This is made for people that are still using Unity 4.xx.

**Unity Ads 2.0** is for those that are running **Unity 5.0.1** or higher.

*[NEW Features](http://response.unity3d.com/brand-ads-beta-release-signup)*:

Unity claims improvement such as new ways to boost your eCPMs and optimized campaign performances in real-time and features that make it easier to explore data across our ad network, and maximize ARPDAU.

- New visualization tool that help you improve your in-game economy and
  the player experience.
- Ability to perform hourly brand ads’ revenue reporting and setting of  categories, such as age and domain filters, makes it easy to find
  relevant info.
- You no longer have to 'mix and match' performance from multiple
  sources and across different networks.